# issue while installing docker for Mac using command line?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, homebrew

I want to install docker using command line not using docker for mac. I have downloaded the individual binary for Mac from this link. 
[docker ce binaries](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/.)

I am able to run docker command but if I run `docker ps` then it shows

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I tried another way to downloading docker using brew as below

```
brew cask install docker
```

But using brew it only download the desktop setup of docker and I have to start it manually.

So I am looking for a solution in which I can install and run docker through command without involving any UI.

Thanks

Comment: I could not find the solution yet by using command line only. I used brew to install docker desktop for mac.

Answer (score 0):

The error above means that the `docker` service is not running so you have to run it first. Then enable it to start on boot - to avoid the need to start it each time you login to your macOS - at the end you should be able to use docker cli without issues

Comment: @TechGuy you may take a look at `pinata` which should be installed with docker for mac it will allow you to manage docker configuration from the command line. a bit old article but might be helpful https://marconijr.com/post/trying-out-docker-beta-for-osx/ as i am not sure if pinata still comes with docker for mac

Comment: What about this command ? `open --hide --background -a Docker` if it works but returns before actually starting docker you can wrap it inside an if condition using bash to make it wait for docker start or something